# How to launch chromium with specific user

Tags: users, chromium, user-profile

The chromium browser allows to have multiple users with individual bookmarks, extension etc. within chromium.

Is it possible to launch chromium with parameters which specify which user to be loaded.

By default the last user is loaded.

Comment: Test if you can find the correct profile directory and get http://superuser.com/questions/377186/how-do-i-start-chrome-using-a-specified-user-profile to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Chromium user profiles

The `chromium-browser` user profiles are stored in specific subfolders of `~/.config/chromium`. These subfolders have names, not obviously corresponding to the user's names.
Let's say I have three user profiles: "Josephine", "Karel", "Willem":

[image: <image1 >]

They are "represented" by three profile folders inside `~/.config/chromium`: `Default`, `Profile 1` and `Profile 2`.
To see which folder is corresponding to which user profile, you'd have to look inside the folder, and see if the *user name* (either "Karel", "Willem" or "Josephine") occurs in the file `Preferences`.

#### To open chromium with a specific user profile

The command to open `chromium` with a specific user profile is:

```
chromium-browser --profile-directory="<name_of_subfolder>"
```

Where the `<name_of_subfolder>` is the name of the folder representing the user, as explained in *Chromium user profiles*. To open `chromium with` "Karel's" profile for example, I will have to run the command:

```
Exec=chromium-browser --profile-directory="Default"
```

#### Options

There are several possibilities to create the option to open with a specific user profile.

1. *Edit the `chromium-browser.desktop` file to open with a specific user by default:*

   - Copy the `chromium-browser.desktop` file from `/usr/share/applications` to `~/.local/share/applications`:

     ```
     cp /usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop
     ```
   - Open the local copy in `~/.local/share/applications` (drag it over an open `gedit` window or run the command `gedit ~/.local/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop`), look for the *first* line, starting with `Exec=`. Replace the line by (in the case of "Karel"):

     ```
     Exec=chromium-browser --profile-directory="Default" %u
     ```

   Save the file and log out/in to see the changes
2. *Alternatively, You can add the user as a shortcut to your launcher:*

   [image: <image2>]

   Look for the line:

   ```
   Actions=NewWindow;Incognito;TempProfile;
   ```

   Change it into:

   ```
   Actions=NewWindow;Incognito;TempProfile;Karel;
   ```

   Add to the very end of the file a section:

   ```
   [Desktop Action Karel]
   Name=Karel
   Exec=chromium-browser --profile-directory="Default"
   OnlyShowIn=Unity;
   ```

   Repeat the procedure for every user you'd like to add as a shortcut (don't forget to log out/in afterwards).
3. *Scripted option:*

   The downside of the two option above is that they are "fixed". You would have to edit your `.desktop` file each and every time a user is added or removed. 
   Another idea is therefore to make a script look up your profiles, extract the corresponding user names in the Preferences files, and make `Zenity` show an option list to choose from:

   [image: < image3>]

   If you call the window from a key shortcut, all you have to to is choose the user from the list (or simply type the number) and press <kbd>Return</kbd>.

   *How to use*

   Copy the script below into an empty file, save it as chromium_profiles.py

   Run it from a shortcut key combination: Choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/chromium_profiles.py
   ```

   *The script*

   ```py
   #!/usr/bin/env python3
   import subprocess
   import os

   home = os.environ["HOME"]
   directory = home+"/"+".config/chromium"
   profiles = []

   user = lambda cmd: subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd]).decode("utf-8")
   reduce = lambda s: s[0].split(": ")[1].replace(",\n", "").replace('"', "")

   def read(file):
       with open(file) as src:
           lines = src.readlines(); r_ls = range(len(lines))
           da = [i for i in r_ls if '"local_profile_id":' in lines[i]][0]
           return reduce([lines[i] for i in r_ls if i > da and '"name"' in lines[i]])

   for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
       for file in files:
           if file.startswith("Preferences"):
               file = root+"/"+file; pr_name = read(file); pr_id = root.split("/")[-1]
               profiles.append([pr_name, pr_id])

   strings = [item[0] for item in profiles]
   list_items = [str(i+1)+". "+strings[i] for i in range(len(strings))]

   try:
       choose = 'zenity --list '+'"'+('" "').join(list_items)+\
                '"'+' --column="User profiles" '+\
                '--title="Chromium users" --height 250 --width 150'
       choice = profiles[int(user(choose)[0])-1]
       command = 'chromium-browser --profile-directory="'+choice[1]+'"'
       subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", command])
   except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
       pass
   ```

Comment: While the `--profile-directory` hint would have been enough for me, the rest of the answer might produce some nice up votes by others ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your tip for doing the `cp /usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop .local/share/applications/` and adding `--profile-directory="Default"` in the correct place keeps me sane.